# How to reference stage? Using flex for Facebook actionscript mobile API login method

Tags: android, flash, apache-flex, facebook, stage

I'm trying to implement the 1.6 Mobile Facebook API (http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/downloads/detail?name=GraphAPI_Mobile_1_6.swc) into an Air for Android application. I've succesfully used the Web and Desktop API's however with the mobile app it's expecting an extra parameter to a stageReference, see:

```
login(callback:Function, stageRef:Stage, extendedPermissions:Array, webView:StageWebView = null)
```

But, using i'm using Flex and not Flash CS5, i can't just pass in this.stage or this or anything like that.

What exactly would you guys think I need to pass into that using Flash builder Flex? I can't seem to find any examples for the mobile actionscript API so i'm kinda in the dark, anyone have any ideas?

Here's the login information from the Mobile API Docs:

```
login   ()  method   
public static function login(callback:Function, stageRef:Stage, extendedPermissions:Array, webView:StageWebView = null):void
Opens a new login window so the current user can log in to Facebook.

Parameters

callback:Function — The method to call when login is successful. The handler must have the signature of callback(success:Object, fail:Object); Success will be a FacebookSession if successful, or null if not.

stageRef:Stage — A reference to the stage

extendedPermissions:Array — (Optional) Array of extended permissions to ask the user for once they are logged in.

webView:StageWebView (default = null) — (Optional) The instance of StageWebView to use for the login window For the most current list of extended permissions, visit http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Flex, you have `FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication` which will point to your `mx:Application` or `s:Application` so you can call `stage` on that to get a reference to it.

Otherwise, any `DisplayObject` attached to the stage or attached to another `DisplayObject` attached to the `stage`, will have it's `stage` property set (If it's not attached to anything, `stage` will be `null`).

Other than that, normally what people do is keep a static somewhere that they can access through the code, that's set when the program starts. For example, your typical main class could be something like:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        public static var stage:Stage = null;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            // if we have our stage, go directly to _init(), otherwise wait
            if ( this.stage ) this._init();
            else this.addEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, this._init );
        }

        private function _init( e:Event = null ):void 
        {
            // remove the listener
            this.removeEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, this._init );

            // hold the stage
            Main.stage = this.stage;

            // do everything else
            ...
        }

    }

}
```

After that, anywhere in your code, you can call `Main.stage` to get access to the `stage`.

Comment: I actually don't have a main class, i'm doing everything in the mxml file. I remember back when i used Flash Pro I would have a Main class similr to what you're showing here. Should I make a main class file and just reference it that way? Or should i just put your code in my creationcomplete function in my mxml file? Sorry just a little unsure

Comment: You do have a main class - it's your mxml file. Your main class is just the class that's run when the application starts. You can still keep a static in the class, but as you're using Flex, the `FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.stage` should work for you

Comment: FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.stage seemed to do the trick, it accepts it and doesn't crash. however, im just getting a white screen(which looks like its starting to open a webview im assuming to display the facebook connect dialog), then switches back. if i add a break point its just getting a fail result. which makes me wonder if the right information was added. I duno, i doubt you're familir with the facebook api. Anyway, what you said did what i needed i think, ill report back if apparently thats not what it was expecting. so it makes sense to mark as the answer for now, thanks!

Comment: perhaps you need to actually run it on mobile for it to work as it might be trying to interact with the phone browser or something